# Как правильно реализовать KVO для TextField?

Tags: xcode, macos, objective-c

Мне необходимо выполнить наблюдение за полем TextField1 и при изменении его значения, перенести его текст в TextField2. Пытался реализовать это следующим образом:

```
//.h
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextFieldCell *text1;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextFieldCell *text2;

//.m
-(id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath: @"text1" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    [self.text2 setStringValue:[self.text1 stringValue]];
}
```

Ничего не действует. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Я не прогаю под mac os, но у меня вопрос: почему вы используете NSTextFieldCell, а не просто NSTextField ?

Comment: Это Xcode при создание с помощью стрелок (ctr) сделал NSTextFieldCell. А сам я тоже при ручном способе использую NSTextField.

Comment: Понял, сейча пробую. Если получится - запишу видео

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ссылка на видео http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mThWEZDkIpg
(Не самое лучшее решение, но работает)

Можно использовать биндинг: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSwePi2LsjM (Это решение мне кажется лучшим)

Comment: Я нигде не могу найти этот метод "Value Changed".

Comment: врете, этот метод, во-первых, вызывается до изменения (он проверяет саму возможность такого изменения, например, если вы вбиваете какой-нибудь номер телефона и вам необходимо  проверить что первый символ либо 8 либо +7). Вот второй вариант с событием ValueChanged работает, хотя по-моему и у делегата есть подобный метод, но это надо смотреть в доках

Comment: Value Changed - это по моему в Cocoa Touch, а в Cocoa для Mac OS такого метода нет.

Comment: derkode, топикстартер изменил вопрос. Изначально речи о Mac OS не шло.

Comment: Я добавил тег "macos", думал достаточно. В следующий раз не поленюсь отметить и в вопросе.

Comment: Сори, не заметил

Comment: Просто СУПЕР!!! Спасибо! Можно спросить, чем видео делал?

Comment: @derkode, Посмотри еще второй вариант решения.
Видео делал через QuickTime Player стандартный.